# What MySQL Collation should I use for Magento?

Tags: database, mysql

It appears I normally use 'utf8_unicode_ci'.   However, I don't know if that is the best collation to use.   I searched Magento StackExchange and was suprised I didn't see a question/answer on this topic, so thought I would post this to see if there is a consensus view on this question.

Comment: Convention in Magento is to use UTF-8 everywhere (page presentation, data gathering and storage). With 1.1 million code points, you have enough glyphs available to support all languages on the planet. Code pages and highly limited language support needs to die.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8_general_ci` will work.

For explanations as to the differences between the two, consult

[What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

to find which will give you better results.

Answer (score 4):

In `Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table` you can find some hardcoded database options stored in the `$_options` variable:

```
protected $_options = ['type' => 'INNODB', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci'];
```

However, as Fiasco Labs' answer point out you can use `utf8_unicode_ci` as well.